# Creating a list of child taxonomy terms with Views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a a taxonomy with 2 levels:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
  - Child 3
- Parent 2

  - Child 4
  - Child 5

When I am on `/taxonomy/term/parent1` I want to display a view of a list of child terms in a block:

- Child 1
- Child 2
- Child 3

I have been through similar questions on this site, some with accepted answers, but it did not help me. Here is my Views settings.

[image]

For now, it displays the term name for each node containing the parent or child term, causing a lot of duplicates.

- parent 1
- parent 1
- child 1
- child 1
- child 2
- child 2

I'm using Views 3 and Drupal 7
If someone has a hint to share it would help me a lot :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Till now what i have tried, its not possible to show child of the current term with view.

Comment: maybe grouping by parent can resolve your problem take [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35524/how-to-create-view-that-display-just-2-level-of-taxonomy-vocabulary) a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong but I guess you have created a View of type 'content' while your intention is to list 'taxonomy terms' (I understand that Child # are taxonomy terms). The type of a View is indicated by the label within parenthesis, above the top of the admin lightbox. If my assumption is right, you would want to create a new View of type 'taxonomy term'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module. I don't know if it will show the subtree of the taxonomy when visiting parents, but the module page says that it integrates with Views.

Comment: This module is available for Drupal 8 also.