# how to create view that display just 2 level of taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

i have a vocabulary that contain plus of 5 level descendant, i need to create the view to display the first 2 levels and grouping by the first one, i do this:

1. **FIELDS**: (Parent) Taxonomy term: Name - Taxonomy term: Name
2. **FILTER CRITERIA**: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (= All Type
   Announce)
3. **SORT CRITERIA**: (Parent) Taxonomy term: Weight (asc)
4. **RELATIONSHIPS**: Taxonomy term: Parent term

and i get all list of taxonomy for this vocabulary grouping by parents, how to set only 2 levels?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. In fact, there is no need to add any relationship in the Views. Just create the taxonomy term view and add a filter criteria of **Taxonomy term: Parent term**. (see screenshot)
Then set the value to be equal to `''`. This will fetch you all the parent terms as they don't have any parent! (`''`)
[image: See the last link]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that this would really help. It would help to be more descriptive with answers rather than pasting a screenshot because images are not accessible for everyone. A detailed list of steps would help compliment your answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should be just fine by introducing 2 chained parent relationships. Setting the criterion where parent of the parent is NULL should work.
Well, this is a purely UI way of doing that, which is a pro. The con is that queries with nested relations might become heavy at some point, therefore consider turning on Views cache when you deploy the site.

Comment: "Artur's" method is pretty good.
The only thig what I want to say is that "Setting the criterion where parent of the parent is NULL" need to be "equal to 0 (zero)".
Also to get it work I had to group terms by parent.